# Twilio: Get RecordingDuration after conference

Tags: twilio

I am trying to get the record duration of a conference chat.

This is what I am trying to do:

I have the following `View()` that starts the conference:

```
@{
    var nextPageUrl =  "https://api.mySite.com/ConferenceFinished/"
}

<Response>
   <Dial timeLimit="600">
        <Conference  record="record-from-start"  eventCallbackUrl="@nextPageUrl" endConferenceOnExit="true">
           Room123
        </Conference>
    </Dial>       
</Response>
```

In `ConferenceFinished()` I am trying to receive the conference record-duration:

```
 public ActionResult ConferenceFinished(int userRequestId, Guid shopUserId)
        {
            var recUrl = Request["RecordingUrl"]; //  successfully received!
            var recordingDuration = Request["RecordingDuration"]; // I am getting nothing!


         }
```

I am getting the `RecordingUrl` but `RecordingDuration` is empty!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When a Conference finishes, it doesn't actually send a `RecordingDuration` parameter. [The documentation shows that only the `RecordingUrl` is sent](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-eventCallbackUrl-parameters).

You could try to get the length of the recording from the file itself. There are good answers on StackOverflow for [how to get the length of an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722501/easiest-way-to-get-mp3-duration-and-size).